# I created variables with for loop and it resulted to KeyError

Tags: python, gurobi

I created a model with gurobi.
I created 3 variables, x,y,w.
But when I'm adding constraints, the first line always has problem. It seems that even x_vars(0,0,0) doesn't even exist. I think I've got something wrong when creating the variables.
I'm been "debugging" for the entire afternoon and it still doesn't work.

```
    # Constants
  Land = 500
  rWheat = 200
  rCorn = 240
  mBeet = 6000
  prob = 1/3
  wheatYield = [3.0,2.5,2.0]
  cornYield = [3.6,3.0,2.4]

 # Model
  mFarm = grb.Model('Farm')
  x_vars
  y_vars
  w_vars
  # Scenarios - A for wheat; B for corn
  SA=3
  SB=3
  for a in range (SA):
    for b in range (SB):
      x_vars = mFarm.addVars([(i,a,b) for i in range(3)],vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS,name="x")
      y_vars = mFarm.addVars([(i,a,b) for i in range(2)],vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS,name="y")
      w_vars = mFarm.addVars([(i,a,b) for i in range(4)],vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS,name="w")
    
  # Constraits 
  for a in range (SA):
    for b in range (SB):
      mFarm.addConstr(grb.quicksum(x_vars[i,a,b] for i in range(2))<=Land)
      mFarm.addConstr(w_vars[2,a,b]+w_vars[3,a,b]<=x_vars[2,a,b])
      mFarm.addConstr(w_vars[2,a,b]<=mBeet)
      mFarm.addConstr(x_vars[0,a,b]*wheatYield[a]+y_vars[0,a,b]-w_vars[0,a,b]>=rWheat)
      mFarm.addConstr(x_vars[1,a,b]*cornYield[b]+y_vars[1,a,b]-w_vars[1,a,b]>=rCorn)
```

[my Google colab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UFaq.png)

I got the message of

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-cb120c86edd9> in <module>()
     25 for a in range (SA):
     26   for b in range (SB):
---> 27     mFarm.addConstr(grb.quicksum(x_vars[i,a,b] for i in range(2))<=Land)
     28     mFarm.addConstr(w_vars[2,a,b]+w_vars[3,a,b]<=x_vars[2,a,b])
     29     mFarm.addConstr(w_vars[2,a,b]<=mBeet)

src/gurobipy/gurobi.pxi in gurobipy.quicksum()

<ipython-input-95-cb120c86edd9> in <genexpr>(.0)
     25 for a in range (SA):
     26   for b in range (SB):
---> 27     mFarm.addConstr(grb.quicksum(x_vars[i,a,b] for i in range(2))<=Land)
     28     mFarm.addConstr(w_vars[2,a,b]+w_vars[3,a,b]<=x_vars[2,a,b])
     29     mFarm.addConstr(w_vars[2,a,b]<=mBeet)

KeyError: (0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Have no idea what gurobi is, but error suggest that there is no entry for key `(0, 0, 0)` maybe you are overrating previous entries as you use `=` instead of `+=`?

Answer (score 1):

You should create the variables like this:

```
x_vars = mFarm.addVars(3, SA, SB, vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS,name="x")
y_vars = mFarm.addVars(2, SA, SB, vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS,name="y")
w_vars = mFarm.addVars(4, SA, SB, vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS,name="w")
```

In your code, you are overwriting the Python variables `x_vars`, `y_vars`, and `w_vars` in every iteration of the loops, so eventually, you end up with just the final set of variables `[i, 2, 2]`.

Please refer to the documentation of [Model.addVars()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_addvars.html) for further information.

Then, you can construct the constraints like in your code, referencing them via the respective indices, although you might want to check out [Model.addConstrs()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_addconstrs.html) for a more compact version similar to addVars.

Side note: In Python, it is not necessary to declare the variables before you assign them.

Comment: You correctly identify the problem. Thank you! I printed the vars and it only has (0, 2, 2),(1, 2, 2),(2, 2, 2). You're very good at this! TYSM

Comment: Thanks! Then, please also mark my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark. Otherwise your question will remain "unanswered".